# Why isnt my pagination working in the while post loop?! Help would be much appreciated, new to PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have this code down below, showing 16 posts and on the next page the next 16 but right now it's not getting new posts on the second + page. It is showing the same first 16 that it shows on the first page. I don't know where I went wrong and why its not communicating with the while loop?

```
    $cat = get_the_category();
    $cat_name = esc_html($cat[0]->name);
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'category_name' => $cat_name,
        'posts_per_page' => 16,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'offset' => 5

    );

    $all_catPosts = null;
    $all_catPosts = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($all_catPosts->have_posts()) {

        ?>
    <!-- 16 category container with the next page pagination button -->
    <div class="min-h-screen flex items-center justify-center">
        <div class="grid grid-cols-4">
    <?php
        while ($all_catPosts->have_posts()): $all_catPosts->the_post();?>
            <div class="p-5 rounded big_cat_container">
            <!-- // all content, title, meta fields-->
                <section><a class="thumbnail_img" href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail();?></a></section>
                <h4 class="post_title"><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h4>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile;?>
        </div><!--/ end of grid-->

        <!-- //pagination buttons -->
        <?php 
        $previousLink = get_previous_posts_link();
        $nextLink = get_next_posts_link();
        $hasNextPage = $previousLink || $nextLink;

        if ($hasNextPage):?>
            <nav class="pagination" role="navigation">
                <?php if($previousLink || $paged > 1 ) { ?>
                    <div class="page-btn nav-next">
                    <button class="previous-btn"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Previous Page',  ); ?></button>
                    </div>
                <?php } 
                if($nextLink) { ?>
                    <div class="page-btn nav-previous">
                        <button class="next-btn">
                        <?php next_posts_link( 'Next Page ', $the_query->max_num_pages );?>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </nav>
        <?php endif;?>
        <!-- end pagination -->

    </div><!--/ end of container-->

    <?php } ?>

<?php 
// clean up after the query and pagination
wp_reset_postdata(); 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
              <?php 
                $cat = get_the_category();
                $cat_name = esc_html($cat[0]->name);
                $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
            
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'category_name' => $cat_name,
                    'posts_per_page' => 16,
                    'paged' => $paged,
                    'orderby' => 'date',
                    'order' => 'DESC',
                    'offset' => 5
            
                );
            
                $all_catPosts = null;
                $all_catPosts = new WP_Query($args);
            
                if ($all_catPosts->have_posts()) {
            
                    ?>
                <!-- 16 category container with the next page pagination button -->
                <div class="min-h-screen flex items-center justify-center">
                    <div class="grid grid-cols-4">
                <?php
                    while ($all_catPosts->have_posts()): $all_catPosts->the_post();?>
                        <div class="p-5 rounded big_cat_container">
                        <!-- // all content, title, meta fields-->
                            <section><a class="thumbnail_img" href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail();?></a></section>
                            <h4 class="post_title"><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h4>
                        </div>
                    <?php endwhile;?>
                    </div><!--/ end of grid-->
                    <!-- //pagination buttons -->
                    <?php 
                    $previousLink = get_previous_posts_link();
                    $nextLink = get_next_posts_link();
                    $hasNextPage = $previousLink || $nextLink;
            
                    if ($hasNextPage):?>
                        <nav class="pagination" role="navigation">
                            <?php if($previousLink || $paged > 1 ) { ?>
                                <div class="page-btn nav-next">
                                <button class="previous-btn"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Previous Page',  ); ?></button>
                                </div>
                            <?php } 
                            if($nextLink) { ?>
                                <div class="page-btn nav-previous">
                                    <button class="next-btn">
                                    <?php next_posts_link( 'Next Page ', $all_catPosts->max_num_pages );?>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </nav>
                    <?php endif;?>
                    <!-- end pagination -->
            
                </div><!--/ end of container-->
            
                <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Please try now,i just updated the $the_query variable with $all_catPosts object variable. it should work!

Comment: Hi Deepak! Thank you for the help but its still showing the same 16 results, its not looping even after pluggin in the $all_catPosts

Comment: @VanessaO i have just posted another answer try to use this simple post previous next pagination loop if it works fine then do the parameter modifications as per your requirement. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?php
 
   $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
     
    // the query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 16,
        'paged' => $paged
    );
     
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
        // the loop
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
            the_title();
             
        endwhile;
     
        // next_posts_link() usage with max_num_pages.
        next_posts_link( __( 'Older Entries', 'textdomain' ), $the_query->max_num_pages );
        previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer Entries', 'textdomain' ) );
     
        // Clean up after the query and pagination.
        wp_reset_postdata(); 
     
    else:
        ?>
        <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.', 'textdomain' ) ); ?></p>
        <?php
    endif;
```

Comment: I figured out what was breaking the pagination..its the offet. Apparently using offet with pagination breaks it. I used offet because I want to start at the fifth index of posts. Not at the first hmm

Comment: Okay, great! 
You can use offset like this way see solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49227520/how-can-i-paginate-wp-query-results-when-theres-an-offset